# Escaped quote in json body response

Tags: json, node.js, oracle, typescript, swagger

Here is my issue:

I get data from Oracle, log them in my service with a simple `console.log` and everything is ok the JSON has a good format. It's for a GET request.

Example : `{ "metadata":[{"client"...`

Then at the end of the GET I do `res.status(200).json(responsJson);` to return th result.

In swagger Ui or postman the response body is displayed with every quote escaped :

example : `{ \"metadata\":[{\"client\":...`

Why is that ?

Comment: Is it that you are passing a string in JSON format (rather than an object) - so it gets encoded as a string with the quotes escaped. What happens if you do `res.status(200).json(JSON.parse( responsJson ) );`?

Comment: It just get me an error

Comment: Use `res.status(200).send(responsJson);`

Comment: It works with send() but seems like a workaround

Comment: Could you post `responsJson` in your question

Comment: Using send() corrected my issue. responseJson has the format of the second example